# Unknown name "time_to_live" at 'message':

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send push notification via firebase:

```
await admin.messaging().sendAll({
token: 'some token',
data: {val1: '1', val2: '2'},
time_to_live: 300,
});
```

I am getting next error:

> {"message":"Send push notification failed, Invalid JSON payload
> received. Unknown name "time_to_live" at 'message': Cannot find
> field.","level":"error"}

Comment: Hi, can you provide a reference to the exact API method you are using? Is this part of Admin SDK?

Answer (score 1):

In firebase for `time_to_live` the key is `ttl`, also I use this request body for sending push notifications in android apps:

```
const body = {
  notification: {
    title: 'xxxx',
    body: "xxxxxxxx"
  },
  data: {
    notification_message: "xxxxxx"
  },
  token: 'xxxxxx',
  android: {
    ttl: 3600,
    notification: { icon: 'xxxxx', color: '#b2b2b2' }
  }
}

await admin.messaging().send(body)
```

Use `ttl` key in case of `time_to_live`.

Comment: what about IOS?

Comment: sorry i dont know about iOS, if we can use firebase for iOS or not. I have used [apn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn) for ios not firebase.